# Will aggregate-per-site data from the moderator engagement survey be made public?

Tags: support, moderator-satisfaction-survey

From [the first July 2018 moderator newsletter](//stackmod.blog/2018/07/july-2018-newsletter/):

> We’re starting a yearly tradition by sending out a short engagement survey to all moderators…. The survey is completely optional and anonymous; aggregate data that is not free-form in nature will be made public in a way that doesn’t identify individuals.

Will such aggregate data be available on a site-by-site basis? The reason I ask is: If so, then for a site with (e.g.) only three moderators it may be easy to identify who answered what even if no names are attached to the answers.

Comment: ...and in the "Judaism mods with digits in their names" category...

Comment: I hope they'll be careful with that, as I know that some of my answers uniquely identify me. ("On some of my sites...")

Comment: *"it may be easy to identify who answered what"* This is pretty much a non-issue unless the moderator is in the habit of hiding their true feelings on issues. In any case, anonymous surveys are rarely (if at all) anonymous, especially when administered online, so moderators who are uncomfortable with something being disclosed publicly should avoid posting it in the first place.

Comment: @MaskedMan I haven't looked at the questions yet (I'm awaiting an official answer to this question before taking the survey) but can imagine there may be some whose answers one would not mind sending to a handful of SE employees but would prefer to hide from his millions of fellow SE users.

Comment: @msh2010 Even so, it only applies to the "non-free form" data, if you go by their statement. Regardless, when taking these "anonymous" surveys, it is always better to err on the side of caution. In any case, if the moderator has to hide their feelings about the site from their own community, there is something wrong somewhere. Of course, that doesn't apply to PII and other data that moderators access as part of their duty.